# How to add ArcGIS server layer using leaflet.esri package?

Tags: r, leaflet, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

I am trying to add a layer from a published ArcGIS service feature into a leaflet map in R using the leaflet.esri package.

I've read the documentations here https://rdrr.io/cran/leaflet.esri/man/addEsriTiledMapLayer.html and here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet.esri/leaflet.esri.pdf and have tested the examples

My code looks like this:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.esri)

leaflet() %>% setView(lng = 55.0876632, lat = 25.0755935, zoom = 10) %>% 
  addEsriTiledMapLayer(
  url = "https://smart.gis.gov.ae/dmgis104/rest/services/Misc/Env_Imagery/MapServer")
```

Update:  Note that no username or password is required.

I've confirmed that url works by adding it as an ArcGIS server in ArcCatalog, but when I try to run the above in R I just get a blank leaflet map.

How do I specify which layer from the above url to load?  There are a number of layers available at that url, such as "Misc/IMAGE2018" and I would like to load these into leaflet.

I am a bit confused as well because when I inspect the url in ArcCatlog it shortens it to "Server URL:  https://smart.gis.gov.ae/dmgis104/services" instead of the above, but I am not sure if that matters.  See screen shot below as example of ArcCatlog.

[image: Screenshot of ArcCatlog connection]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

the issue is that your map service doesn't use the typical web mercator projection and tiling scheme.

you can find an example which includes extra code to explicitly define a custom projection here: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/non-mercator-projection.html

Comment: I'd also recommend reading this: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/tutorials/introduction-to-layer-types.html